# Что нужно сделать, чтобы выпадающий список менял свой размер в зависимости от количества текста?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо чтобы текст был в линию, и размер выпадающего списка был пошире.
Как это выглядит - https://skr.sh/sGLB7m0JfA4

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  margin-top: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: rgba(200, 150, 40, .15);
}

nav ul li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}

nav ul li {
  float: left;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  background: #1c1c1c;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  top: 70%;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px -2px rgba(200, 150, 40, .1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(200, 150, 40, .1);
}

nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 30px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(200, 150, 40, .05);
  margin-top: 0px;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav role='navigation'>
  <li><a href="#">список</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="/">это просто выпадающий список</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="/">это просто выпадающий список</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</nav>
```

Comment: > чтобы текст был в линию. - Чтобы текст не переносился на другую строку?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание на св-во: `position: absolute/relative`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  border: solid red;

  word-break: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  
  position: relative;
  
  list-style: none;
  border: solid green;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid yellow;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  
}

nav ul li ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      dropdown 1
      <ul>
        <li>кнопка</li>
        <li>кнопка</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      dropdown 2
      <ul>
        <li>кнопка</li>
        <li>кнопка</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    
    <li>
      dropdown 3
      <ul>
        <li>кнопка</li>
        <li>кнопка</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```